# Flutter- FCM with Local notification and alert

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is first time I am testing FCM with Flutter. I checked some of the SO questions and documents from GitHub.

I am able to send the notifications and they are getting delivered when the app is not running.

If app is running or in the background then messages are not visible.

I have added the code in main.dart file but not sure this is the correct way or not.

**Edit:**
This is for onResume:

```
{notification: {}, data: {badge: 1, collapse_key: com.HT, google.original_priority: high, google.sent_time: 1623238, google.delivered_priority: high, sound: default, google.ttl: 2419200, from: 71374876, body: Body, title: Title, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, google.message_id: 0:50a56}}
```

In the Below code, i am trying to use local notifications with FCM.

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging();
  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  @override
  void initState() {
    var initializationSettingsAndroid =
        new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var initializationSettingsIOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initializationSettings = new InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid, iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
    _firebaseMessaging.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        showNotification(
            message['notification']['title'], message['notification']['body']);
        print("onMessage: $message");
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
        // Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/notify');
        ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
          Routes.bookingQRScan,
        );
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
      },
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: AnimatedSplashScreen(), //SplashScreen()

      builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder<a.Router>(router: a.Router()),
    );
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (_) {
        return new AlertDialog(
          title: Text("PayLoad"),
          content: Text("Payload : $payload"),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  void showNotification(String title, String body) async {
    await _demoNotification(title, body);
  }

  Future<void> _demoNotification(String title, String body) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel_ID', 'channel name', 'channel description',
        importance: Importance.max,
        playSound: false, //true,
        //sound: 'sound',
        showProgress: true,
        priority: Priority.high,
        ticker: 'test ticker');

    //var iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'test');
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
This is when my app is running on foreground. E/FlutterFcmService(14434): Fatal: failed to find callback
W/FirebaseMessaging(14434): Missing Default Notification Channel metadata in AndroidManifest. Default value will be used.
W/ConnectionTracker(14434): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(14434): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lu@fb04880
Notification is visible in notification center. Now i am clicking on it and app get terminated.
and new instance of app is running and below is the return code. I/flutter (14434): onResume: {notification: {}, data: {badge: 1, collapse_key: com.HT, google.original_priority: high, google.sent_time: 1607733798, google.delivered_priority: high, sound: default, google.ttl: 2419200, from: 774876, body: Body, title: Title, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, google.message_id: 0:1607573733816296%850a56}}
E/FlutterFcmService(14434): Fatal: failed to find callback
W/ConnectionTracker(14434): Exception thrown while unbinding
```

**Edit 2:**
I did more digging and come up with the below code.

```
final FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();

  FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  var initializationSettingsAndroid;
  var initializationSettingsIOS;
  var initializationSettings;

  void _showNotification() async {
    //await _buildNotification();
  }

  Future<dynamic> myBackgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
    if (message.containsKey('data')) {
      // Handle data message
      final dynamic data = message['data'];
    }

    if (message.containsKey('notification')) {
      // Handle notification message

      final dynamic notification = message['notification'];
    }

    // Or do other work.
  }

  Future<void> _createNotificationChannel(
      String id, String name, String description) async {
    final flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var androidNotificationChannel = AndroidNotificationChannel(
      id,
      name,
      description,
      importance: Importance.max,
      playSound: true,
      // sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('not_kiddin'),
      enableVibration: true,
    );
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .resolvePlatformSpecificImplementation<
            AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin>()
        ?.createNotificationChannel(androidNotificationChannel);
  }

  Future<void> _buildNotification(String title, String body) async {
    var androidPlatformChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'my_channel', 'Channel Name', 'Channel Description.',
        importance: Importance.max,
        priority: Priority.high,
        //  playSound: true,
        enableVibration: true,
        //  sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('not_kiddin'),
        ticker: 'noorderlicht');
    //var iOSChannelSpecifics = IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin
        .show(0, title, body, platformChannelSpecifics, payload: 'payload');
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    initializationSettingsIOS = IOSInitializationSettings(
        onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceiveLocalNotification);

    initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(android: initializationSettingsAndroid);
    // initializationSettingsAndroid, initializationSettingsIOS);

    _fcm.requestNotificationPermissions();

    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print(message);
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
            onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);

        //_showNotification();
        Map.from(message).map((key, value) {
          print(key);
          print(value);
          print(value['title']);
          _buildNotification(value['title'], value['body']);
        });
      },
      onLaunch: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onLaunch: $message");
      },
      onResume: (Map<String, dynamic> message) async {
        print("onResume: $message");
        print(message['data']['title']);
        //AlertDialog(title: message['data']['title']);
        ExtendedNavigator.of(context).push(
          Routes.bookingQRScan,
        );
        //_showNotification();
      },
    );
  }

  Future onDidReceiveLocalNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, String payload) async {
    // display a dialog with the notification details, tap ok to go to another page
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) => CupertinoAlertDialog(
        title: Text(title),
        content: Text(body),
        actions: [
          CupertinoDialogAction(
            isDefaultAction: true,
            child: Text('Ok'),
            onPressed: () {},
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('Notification payload: $payload');
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: AnimatedSplashScreen(), //SplashScreen()

      builder: ExtendedNavigator.builder<a.Router>(router: a.Router()),
    );
  }
```

With above code i can see notifications in notification bar but onresume section i want to redirection that is not working. Not sure why.

Also I want to show alert box in onmeesage and onresume events.

Comment: please post your payload

Comment: It has been added in the question.

Comment: you payload is wrong, as I experienced that the notification key must-have title and body parameters and data json object should also contain title and body key.

Comment: ok thanks for the comment. I made a little more changes based on your suggestions and testing the same. One more thing if the app is in the background then do I get the alert in app once i click the notification or it will only open the app.

Comment: you can redirect to any screen where you want , if you do not put any condition then it will open the app only.

Comment: can you show me some example of redirect? And do i need to define FCMNotification on all pages or only configure it on main.dart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your (last edited) code above, I think first you have to make sure, whether localnotifications is used or the default fcm one. Since your myBackgroundMessageHandler does not do anything, I assume the latter one. Try replacing the title temporarily with a fixed string (e.g. "this is a local one") to make sure.

Secondly, myBackgroundMessageHandler will only be called for data messages. If you use the payload you wrote in the beginning, you should be fine. Anyway make sure to not put title, body, style-information etc directly in the payload. If you need it, put it in the data node.

This is the code I am using:

```
calling the notificationService init() method in main.dart
```

notification-service.dart

```
import 'package:flutter_dotenv/flutter_dotenv.dart';
import 'package:app/models/data-notification.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'dart:io';

FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin notificationsPlugin =
    FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

//Function to handle Notification data in background. 
Future<dynamic> backgroundMessageHandler(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  print("FCM backgroundMessageHandler $message");
  showNotification(DataNotification.fromPushMessage(message['data']));
  return Future<void>.value();
}

//Function to handle Notification Click.
Future<void> onSelectNotification(String payload) {
  print("FCM onSelectNotification");
  return Future<void>.value();
}

//Function to Parse and Show Notification when app is in foreground
Future<dynamic> onMessage(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  print("FCM onMessage $message");
  showNotification(DataNotification.fromPushMessage(message['data']));
  return Future<void>.value();
}

//Function to Handle notification click if app is in background
Future<dynamic> onResume(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  print("FCM onResume $message");
  return Future<void>.value();
}

//Function to Handle notification click if app is not in foreground neither in background
Future<dynamic> onLaunch(Map<String, dynamic> message) {
  print("FCM onLaunch $message");
  return Future<void>.value();
}

void showNotification(DataNotification notification) async {
  final AndroidNotificationDetails androidPlatformChannelSpecifics =
      await getAndroidNotificationDetails(notification);

  final NotificationDetails platformChannelSpecifics =
      NotificationDetails(android: androidPlatformChannelSpecifics);

  await notificationsPlugin.show(
    0,
    notification.title,
    notification.body,
    platformChannelSpecifics,
  );
}

Future<AndroidNotificationDetails> getAndroidNotificationDetails(
    DataNotification notification) async {
  switch (notification.notificationType) {
    case NotificationType.NEW_INVITATION:
    case NotificationType.NEW_MEMBERSHIP:
    case NotificationType.NEW_ADMIN_ROLE:
    case NotificationType.MEMBERSHIP_BLOCKED:
    case NotificationType.MEMBERSHIP_REMOVED:
    case NotificationType.NEW_MEMBERSHIP_REQUEST:
      return AndroidNotificationDetails(
          'organization',
          'Organization management',
          'Notifications regarding your organizations and memberships.',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          showWhen: false,
          category: "Organization",
          icon: 'my_app_icon_simple',
          largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('my_app_icon'),
          styleInformation: await getBigPictureStyle(notification),
          sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('slow_spring_board'));
    case NotificationType.NONE:
    default:
      return AndroidNotificationDetails('general', 'General notifications',
          'General notifications that are not sorted to any specific topics.',
          importance: Importance.max,
          priority: Priority.high,
          showWhen: false,
          category: "General",
          icon: 'my_app_icon_simple',
          largeIcon: DrawableResourceAndroidBitmap('my_app_icon'),
          styleInformation: await getBigPictureStyle(notification),
          sound: RawResourceAndroidNotificationSound('slow_spring_board'));
  }
}

Future<BigPictureStyleInformation> getBigPictureStyle(
    DataNotification notification) async {
  if (notification.imageUrl != null) {
    print("downloading");
    final String bigPicturePath =
        await _downloadAndSaveFile(notification.imageUrl, 'bigPicture');

    return BigPictureStyleInformation(FilePathAndroidBitmap(bigPicturePath),
        hideExpandedLargeIcon: true,
        contentTitle: notification.title,
        htmlFormatContentTitle: false,
        summaryText: notification.body,
        htmlFormatSummaryText: false);
  } else {
    print("NOT downloading");
    return null;
  }
}

Future<String> _downloadAndSaveFile(String url, String fileName) async {
  final Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  final String filePath = '${directory.path}/$fileName';
  final http.Response response = await http.get(url);
  final File file = File(filePath);
  await file.writeAsBytes(response.bodyBytes);
  return filePath;
}

class NotificationService {

  FirebaseMessaging _fcm = FirebaseMessaging();

  void init() async {
    final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('app_icon');

    final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        IOSInitializationSettings();

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
      android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      iOS: initializationSettingsIOS,
    );

    await notificationsPlugin.initialize(initializationSettings,
        onSelectNotification: (value) => onSelectNotification(value));

    _fcm.configure(
      onMessage: onMessage,
      onBackgroundMessage: backgroundMessageHandler,
      onLaunch: onLaunch,
      onResume: onResume,
    );
  }
}
```

data-notification.dart

```
import 'package:enum_to_string/enum_to_string.dart';

class DataNotification {
  final String id;
  final String title;
  final String body;
  final NotificationType notificationType;
  final String imageUrl;
  final dynamic data;
  final DateTime readAt;
  final DateTime createdAt;
  final DateTime updatedAt;

  DataNotification({
    this.id,
    this.title,
    this.body,
    this.notificationType,
    this.imageUrl,
    this.data,
    this.readAt,
    this.createdAt,
    this.updatedAt,
  });

  factory DataNotification.fromPushMessage(dynamic data) {
    return DataNotification(
      id: data['id'],
      title: data['title'],
      body: data['body'],
      notificationType: EnumToString.fromString(
          NotificationType.values, data['notification_type']),
      imageUrl: data['image_url'] ?? null,
      data: data,
      readAt: null,
      createdAt: null,
      updatedAt: null,
    );
  }
}

enum NotificationType {
  NONE,
  NEW_INVITATION,
  NEW_MEMBERSHIP,
  NEW_ADMIN_ROLE,
  MEMBERSHIP_BLOCKED,
  MEMBERSHIP_REMOVED,
  NEW_MEMBERSHIP_REQUEST
}
```

You can ignore the DataNotification model part, and parse the notification yourself, I just used it for some additional interactions with in the backend.

This works well for me, however, if you want to show an alert for "onSelectNotification" or alike, you need to find a way to get the context there. Not (yet) sure, how to do that.

EDIT:
You can call it like this in main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  NotificationService().init();

  runApp(
    MyApp()
  );
}
```

Be aware that there is currently an issue with backgroundmessaging and hot-reloading: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/4316

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will read your code and will let you know. One more thing i want to know. If i am on different page then do i get the notification or i need to define it on that page to  or some kind of service needs to create.

Comment: Not sure if i understood you correctly.

It's not necessary to initialize fcm on a certain page. You can do it in main.dart, or through a service like above.
Doing it on a page, it might have unwanted problems with states etc, not sure.
At least all functions you use in the backgroundMessageHandler must be global or static apparently - although I can't find where I read that atm.

Comment: Hey Chris, Sorry i was away for couple of days. Now i am back and using your code as it is just for testing purpose later will make changes in it based on the need. Just one thing i want to know about calling the notificationService init() method in main.dart. You are talking about this NotificationService() or something else.

Comment: i put the NotificationService like this but during debugging i don't see it is getting triggered. void initState() {
    super.initState();
    NotificationService();
  }

Comment: Thanks for the update Chris. I am already using io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin.registerWith(registry?.registrarFor("io.flutter.plugins.firebasemessaging.FirebaseMessagingPlugin"));
 in application kotlen file.

Comment: i am still getting this error. ConnectionTracker(  995): Exception thrown while unbinding
W/ConnectionTracker(  995): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered: lu@8bc68f8
W/ConnectionTracker(  995):  at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1759)
W/ConnectionTracker(  995):  at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1786) checking why i am getting the error.

Comment: Hm, did you do, what the docs suggest, (the intent filter, reference the application.kt in the manifest, etc)? Maybe you might have missed a step there?

Comment: It is working fine. Now i am trying to do the redirection without context. Will let you know if i found something. Also i need to show some popup. So, working on that too.

Comment: Cool, congrats. Regarding popup and navigation I guess you have to work with onresume and onlaunch, since the app cannot navigate or handle popups when closed.
check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59581554/flutter-fcm-navigation-onresume-onlaunch

Comment: Thanks Chris. i might need to use lister or some services I need to handle it during the app is in the foreground.

Comment: two things just for understanding. How to show the notification on lockscreen like whatsapp and how to do the grouping instead of one after one on lockscreen. I used visibility: NotificationVisibility.public, with your code but it is not showing on lock screen. Are you showing notification on lock screen?

Comment: I'm afraid I have not progressed so far yet - so I also don't know ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Your payload must be correct, `notification` and `data` object inside the payload must contain the `title` and `body` key. you will get `title` and `body` null when your app is closed in `notification` key in that situation you should have title and body in the side data key.

```
{notification: {title: title, body: test}, data: {notification_type: Welcome, body: body, badge: 1, sound: , title: farhana mam, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, message: H R U, category_id: 2, product_id: 1, img_url: }}
```

and don't put title and body null

```
void showNotification(Map<String, dynamic> msg) async {
    //{notification: {title: title, body: test}, data: {notification_type: Welcome, body: body, badge: 1, sound: , title: farhana mam, click_action: FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK, message: H R U, category_id: 2, product_id: 1, img_url: }}
    print(msg);
    print(msg['data']['title']);
    var title = msg['data']['title'];
    var msge = msg['data']['body'];

    var android = new AndroidNotificationDetails(
        'channel id', 'channel NAME', 'CHANNEL DESCRIPTION',
        priority: Priority.High, importance: Importance.Max);
    var iOS = new IOSNotificationDetails();
    var platform = new NotificationDetails(android, iOS);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(0, title, msge, platform,
        payload: msge);
  }
```

for redirection

```
FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = new FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
    var android = new AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');
    var iOS = new IOSInitializationSettings();
    var initSetttings = new InitializationSettings(android, iOS);
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(initSetttings, onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification);
    firebaseCloudMessaging_Listeners();

  Future onSelectNotification(String payload) async {
    if (payload != null) {
      debugPrint('notification payload:------ ${payload}');
      await Navigator.push(
        context,
        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => NotificationListing()),
      ).then((value) {});
    }

  }
```

in 'onSelectNotification' you can pass your condition in string parama and you can redirect

(optional, but recommended) If want to be notified in your app (via onResume and onLaunch, see below) when the user clicks on a notification in the system tray include the following intent-filter within the  tag of your android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml:

Comment: Do i need to define the _fcm.configure only once or wherever i need to show the notification during onmessage? Also some suggestions on redirection during onResume.

Comment: I updated the code you can use 'onSelectNotification' method to redirect and you can configure fcm on home screen.

Comment: Let me go through with your code. I will let you know if i stuck anywhere. thanks for your help Farhana.

Comment: I tried your code but it is still not working. I might need more code from your side.

Comment: what problem you are facing, have you tested your firebase to send dummy notification from firebase console.

Comment: i have updated the new code in question. Data is coming from firebase. I can see the  notification but when i click on it my app is getting terminated.

Comment: yes, maybe your application gets terminated because, when you click context is null when your application is full visible then you can navigate. try to put timer.

Comment: and post your issue, when you click what issue you get in the console.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225756/discussion-between-rocx-and-farhana).